# Angular 2 nested component duplicated

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am building a schedule using Angular 2 with nested components.

It appears that Angular 2 has issues displaying data beyond a single child component.

For example I have the following component hierarchy.

- ScheduleComponent
- MonthComponent
- DayComponent

At the second level of nesting, the views stop reflecting the views with integrity.  This is a sample from the month component html when a day component is nested within it and a picture of the result.

```
<div id="list-container">
    <intra-day [day]="days[day]" *ngFor='let day of days'></intra-day>
</div>
```

**results in this**
[image: Error image]

Notice how in September, there are no duplicated days, but in October onward, the 9th of the month is ALWAYS duplicated.

The data does not reflect this.  I have confirmed this by removing the nested component and having the html directly in the MonthComponent html.

```
<div id="list-container">
    <!--<intra-day class="list-container well games" [day]="days[day]" [dayName]="day" *ngFor='let day of dayKeys'></intra-day>-->
    <div *ngFor='let day of dayKeys'>
        <md-list>
            <div class="list-name-container well games" (click)="toGames(game)">
                <h3 md-subheader class="display-inline list-name games date-header">{{day}}</h3>
            </div>
            <intra-game *ngFor="let game of gameKeys" [game]="day.games[game]" [gameKey]="game"></intra-game>
            <button md-button class="add-button" md-button color="primary" (click)="openGameModal(game)">ADD GAME</button>
        </md-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Results in**
[image]
Notice there are no duplicated days. Same data, but different view result.

**Is there a restriction of the number of components that can be nested?  Is there a workaround for this?  I'd rather not put all of my code into one component since that is a huge benefit of using Angular 2.**

Comment: That should work. I have something fairly similar and it works. I noticed here that in your example of working code you are enumerating `dayKeys` but in your failing example you are enumerating `days`.

Comment: "huge benefit of using Angular 2" I I'd say that's hardly the case as Angular 2 punishes you for every component that you extract by forcing you to declare both a template and a view model and register it in an `NgModule`. Component engines like React and Aurelia do this much better.

Comment: @user3331142, just a wild guess - can it be daylight saving transition that breaks some calculations in your code? As I can see your October ends on the 30th day but there are actually 31 days in it...

Comment: @AluanHaddad, that was actually just forgetting to simplify them both.  They are implemented identically.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov, great observation!  I hadn't noticed that the view is showing 31 days, but that the last day shown is the 30th.  I wonder if Angular 2 is shifting them over?  I don't think it's a time zone issue because it is showing correctly on one with the correct display.  Same data, just displayed incorrectly

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to tell what's going on without more information

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov, you were right all the way.  translation of the 9th and 10th days of the month using Date() were resulting in two 9th days of the month.  I fixed the problem by using moment.js